# Can I tell the csc /recurse command to skip a folder?

Tags: c#, .net, csc

We have some legacy tests that use the csc command with the /recurse option to compile some C# code.  We may have a need to tell the csc command to recurse all sub-folders **except** one particular sub-folder.

I've tried using the attrib command with the +H option to mark the folder that we want the command to skip as hidden, but the csc command still finds it.

Any suggestions?